# Performance testing for Android application which uses UDP protocol, how to run jmeter script on android device for UDP requests plugin?

Tags: android, jmeter, udp, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Using UDP requests plugin, I created jmeter script to run on desktop application. Now I am trying to run same jmeter script via Android device. I used 'Https Test script Recorder' but still I doesn't able to run UDP requests on android device. Is there any way to Run UDP requests on Android device ?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as per its name can only capture [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https)

[UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is a different beast hence UDP packets cannot be captured by JMeter.

I would suggest using a lower-level sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) which is capable of [capturing UDP traffic](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Wireshark/UDP) and once you have the request payload you can simulate the request using [UDP Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UDPRequest/) sampler (can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

[image]

Check out [Load Testing UDP - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-udp-the-ultimate-guide/) article to get more information regarding the specifics of the UDP requests simulation using JMeter